# How to add SVG icons using vanilla javascript, dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

How would i add SVG icons using vanilla javascript?
In HTML you just put it in, that's it. On javascript I've tried a ton of things, none worked.
And I'm gonna need to add a bunch, dynamically, based on the user actions.

This is how it's implemented in HTML :

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-settings" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#9E9E9E" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
  <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
  <path d="M10.325 4.317c.426 -1.756 2.924 -1.756 3.35 0a1.724 1.724 0 0 0 2.573 1.066c1.543 -.94 3.31 .826 2.37 2.37a1.724 1.724 0 0 0 1.065 2.572c1.756 .426 1.756 2.924 0 3.35a1.724 1.724 0 0 0 -1.066 2.573c.94 1.543 -.826 3.31 -2.37 2.37a1.724 1.724 0 0 0 -2.572 1.065c-.426 1.756 -2.924 1.756 -3.35 0a1.724 1.724 0 0 0 -2.573 -1.066c-1.543 .94 -3.31 -.826 -2.37 -2.37a1.724 1.724 0 0 0 -1.065 -2.572c-1.756 -.426 -1.756 -2.924 0 -3.35a1.724 1.724 0 0 0 1.066 -2.573c-.94 -1.543 .826 -3.31 2.37 -2.37c1 .608 2.296 .07 2.572 -1.065z" />
  <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="3" />
</svg>
```

dropping the above anywhere in HTML will lead to a 'settings' icon showing up at that location.

Comment: You want only one icon to show or multiple too with help of pure javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's quite simple and one liner:

```js
const svgIcon = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-settings" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#9E9E9E" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"><path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/><path d="M10.325 4.317c.426 -1.756 2.924 -1.756 3.35 0a1.724 1.724 0 0 0 2.573 1.066c1.543 -.94 3.31 .826 2.37 2.37a1.724 1.724 0 0 0 1.065 2.572c1.756 .426 1.756 2.924 0 3.35a1.724 1.724 0 0 0 -1.066 2.573c.94 1.543 -.826 3.31 -2.37 2.37a1.724 1.724 0 0 0 -2.572 1.065c-.426 1.756 -2.924 1.756 -3.35 0a1.724 1.724 0 0 0 -2.573 -1.066c-1.543 .94 -3.31 -.826 -2.37 -2.37a1.724 1.724 0 0 0 -1.065 -2.572c-1.756 -.426 -1.756 -2.924 0 -3.35a1.724 1.724 0 0 0 1.066 -2.573c-.94 -1.543 .826 -3.31 2.37 -2.37c1 .608 2.296 .07 2.572 -1.065z" /><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="3" /></svg>`;


document.getElementById('targetElement').outerHTML += svgIcon;
```

```html
<div id="targetElement"></div>
```